# O que é e qual a diferença entre IIS Local e IIS Express?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, visual-studio, iis

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que faz o "Criar Diretório Virtual" ?

Comment: Diretório virtual é o que aponta para outra pasta, para ser usado no servidor por exemplo, mas localizado em outro local. Basicamente ao adicionar um você pode selecionar qualquer origem, assim tendo diferentes projetos ali, de lugares diferentes, basicamente todo tipo de servidor usa um diretório virtual, até mesmo apache, só que lá é mais manual as coisas.

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente o IIS Express você usará para fazer os testes da sua aplicação, ele é uma versão mais simples e otimizada para os desenvolvedores. Já o IIS Local você usará para deixar sua aplicação em produção.